# Possible to open and write to local files using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

At work I have to repeat this same process multiple times:

1. Open a certain Dreamweaver file.
2. Look for all `<p>` tags and replace then with `<h1>` tags.
3. Look for all `</p>` and replace with `</h1>`.
4. Look for the string `'Welcome'` and replace with `'goodbye'`.
5. Look for `'0:01:00'` and replace with `'01:00'`.
6. Copy everything in that file.
7. Create a new Dreamweaver file and paste everything in the new file.
8. Save the new file in a given directory and call it a certain name, which can be provided as a variable.

I don't need to run the JavaScript from a browser.  It can be a JavaScript file which I just double click on the desktop.

Is it possible for me to do this with JavaScript / jQuery?

Comment: No I don't think you can. Why don't you use Dreamweavers find and replace function?

Comment: It's definitely possible using, e.g. node.js and various libraries, but that's way too much work. Much easier from the command line using, e.g. [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/sed.html)

Comment: it might also be possible using the browser, see  https://gist.github.com/abicky/1089708 and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/File_I_O. I would not recommend it though, it seems labourious.

Comment: @putvande because I need to do it for multiple files and even more files down the road. Would be easy if there is just a script which I can run which will go through all the files and do the same thing to all the files in, say a given directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many other programming languages that you could accomplish this task with but if you really want to use Javascript then you could do the following:

```
var fs = require('fs');

if(process.argv.length < 4) {
  console.log('Usage: node replace.js fromFilePath toFilePath');
  return;
}

from = process.argv[2];
to = process.argv[3];

fs.readFile(from, { encoding: 'utf-8' }, function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('successfully opened file ' + from);
  var rules = {
    '<p>': '<h1>',
    '</p>': '</h1>',
    'Welcome': 'goodbye',
    '0:01:00': '01:00'
  };

  for(var index in rules) {
      console.log('Replacing ' + index + ' with ' + rules[index] + '...');
      data = data.replace(new RegExp(index, 'gi'), rules[index]);
      console.log('Done');
  }

  console.log("Result");
  console.log(data);

  console.log("Writing data to " + to);

  fs.writeFile(to, data, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('It\'s saved!');
  });

});
```

**INSTRUCTIONS**

1. Download node.js from [here](http://nodejs.org/download/)
2. Install it
3. Create a file in `C:\replace.js` (Win) or `~/replace.js` (Mac OS)
4. Put the code from above in `replace.js`
5. Open `cmd` (Ctrl+R on Win) or `Terminal` (on Mac OS)
6. Type `node C:\replace.js <fileToReadFrom> <fileToSaveTo>` on Win or `node ~/replace.js <fileToReadFrom> <fileToSaveTo>` on Mac OS
7. Done